# Recommended amount of a time a nonce should be retained?

Tags: http, security, authentication, hmac, nonce

What is the recommended amount of time a nonce should be retained? Indefinitely? Using a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) as part of HMAC Authentication and ideally the most secure option is to retain it indefinitely, guaranteeing each web request is unique. Curious if there is any best practice regarding retention?